# ApplySymbologyFromLayer

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I am a new user of Python on ArcGis10 i am trying to apply symbology settings to multiple files but to no success. I have tried my own ways copied syntaxes from various places still getting error. The following is the one that make sense to me but What am i doing wrong??

```
import arcpy
... from arcpy import env
... env.workspace = r"C:\Experiments"
... inputLayer = ["b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"]
... 
... symbologyLayer = "a"
... arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (inputLayer, symbologyLayer)
... 
***Runtime error <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: Object: Error in executing tool***
```

Comment: Can we see a bit more of the actual code please. Is your symbology layer a layer in ArcMap or a layer file in the file system? Are they compatable? i.e. you aren't trying to apply a raster layer to a feature layer, a point to a polygon etc.. does the symbology field exist?

Comment: Well this is the complete code that i can write and understand from different sites. I am trying to change the symbology from stretched to classified with a blue colorramp of about 12 images for start

Comment: And it is a layer file in both arc map and on my harddisk. I converted all the Geotiff images to layer to make the environment of my experiment as close as possible to the scripts i got from internet

Comment: I have about 200 something images that are my actual work but testing on sample 12 images. I can easily apply the script for copying symbology to one layer using *arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management("b","a")
<Result 'b'>* but i want to apply the same symbology to other 10 files using 3-4 line of code

Comment: import arcpy
... arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Zi\Downloads\Compressed\TempTest\PakExtr2013_SM"
... inputLayers = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
... symbologyLayer = "1"
... arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (inputLayers, symbologyLayer)

Comment: "a" is a layer, it's not created or opened by the script so therefore it must exist in ArcMap. Your input layer is a list which is not a suitable input as far as I can see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006n000000 but layers "b","c"... should exist in ArcMap as they're not created or opened by the script.

Comment: I should add that python is indentation based and expressing your code on a single line makes it very hard to understand. When you ask your question there is a button for code blocks this is what that is for. Can you please edit the question and format your code.

Comment: Please edit the question.

Comment: Mr. Michael you were right I used the same code but changed all the file names to the actual .tiff original file name which were long but the code worked and changed all the .tiff files to my required symbology settings. I had actually extracted a small area from the .tiff file and named it as a, b, c and so on for the 12 month data. I think I failed to give the extracted files correct extension in the code therefore it was returning an error

Comment: Are you trying to write a Python script tool or just a standalone Python script to run from IDLE or another IDE, or something else?  Please use the edit button beneath you Question to provide this clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need an automative approach and you are new to python I would suggest for you to develop this workflow using [ModelBuilder](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_ModelBuilder/002w00000001000000/).  You can iterate through a directory using [Iterate Rasters](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00400000000z000000.htm) method and apply a layer file to each image (layer file should be created before running the model against one of your rasters).  If you have ArcMap open and the model you can right click on the final output object and enable Add to Display option.  This will add all your rasters with the applied symbology to your map.

The general model would look something like this (my example I used Iterate Features instead of Rasters):

[image]

Models in general may also be exported out a python script (within ModelBuilder Model menu>Export>To Python Script) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem: It is in the list. Sorry, there will be no screen shots as I'm not at work but have just finished sunday roast (pork, with crackling.. yum!).

Now, when executing a script for ArcMap it can be done in the python window or in the toolbox. If you are using a toolbox you want input parameters, layers, with a multivalue=true for the layers to be symbolized and multilayer=false for the layer to copy from. In this example the copy from layer is the first parameter and the copy to layers is the second.

It is similar in the python window but you drag and drop the layer to copy from and then multiselect the to layers and drop them into the command line.

The input parameters become arguments (sys.argv) argument 0 is the full path to the script which can come in handy but the ones that we want are 1 and 2 which we access using `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]`.

```
import arcpy, sys
symbologyLayer = sys.argv[1] # The first argument

from arcpy import env
inputLayers = sys.argv[2] # The second argument, this is a list
for ThisLayer in inputLayers:
  arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (ThisLayer , symbologyLayer)
```

So you can see that the list is not dropped directly into the tool, but by iterating through the list (`for ThisLayer in`) we do it one at a time such that each element in the inputLayers is substituted for ThisLayer and then the tool is executed on ThisLayer.

I hope this helps and will give you a bit of insight going forward to develop python for ArcMap.

Comment: Well i am novice at programing so i have not been able to completely understand your answer i will have to read up further on your answer :) But I do appreciate you taking time to answer my query. I have one more question Is it possible just to simply give a directory path e.g. C:\data\satellite\2013\ as input for "Layers to symbolize" instead of naming each and every file in the code???

Comment: Yes, sort of, you can add layers from a folder, applying symbology on the way, but that's far more complicated. The whole point of the arguments is not to implicitly specify each layer but to give the layers to the program at the time you invoke it... so this time it's A, B, C and next time it's Fred, Mary, John, Frank, Steve. So long as you work within the limitations of AppySymbologyFromLayer it should work just fine for any number of layers in the 'to' list.

Comment: Thanks Michael the model builder approach is quite helpful